# How to trigger jenkins pipeline job by scm change?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I've just started with pipelines in Jenkins and I'm looking for a way to automaticly trigger builds on an scm change.
Before pipelines I used Bitbucket webhook. But now it gives me an exception

> No git jobs using repository:

Apparently in scans all the jobs in a search of those who use the repository. But it doesn't recognize it in this pipeline script

```
node('master')  {

    stage 'Checkout'
    git url: 'ssh://git@git...'
    ...
```

Is there a way to configure it?
Or should I put the script in Jenkinsfile in the repo and then configure the build to use this repository and connect it using the webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your job doesn't have a 'Git' configured (since you have it in a script instead), the job can't use the BitBucket webhook.

Either you should add a job to the pipeline that performs the checkout using Jenkins Git configuration (pull scm) or you should set BitBucket to activate a Jenkins job for each git-push (using BitBucket add-on or post-receive hook).

Answer (score 0):

You may use an old-style job configured to interact with your BitBucket in "the usual way" and trigger your new pipeline job as "Trigger/call builds on other projects" build step from there.